# AngularJS Nested Ng-repeat Counter Decrementation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to decrement a counter within a nested AnguarJs ng-repeat. I know it is a problem of scope, because the increment in the outer ng-repeat works fine, but in the inner ng-repeat is where I have to decrement and that is where I run into the problem (nothing happens). Is there any way to get an inner scope to increment/decrement/affect an outer scope? Here is the code I am working with.

```
<div class = "col-md-12 section-bg-conversations" ng-repeat="o in form.question | filter:searchText | orderBy:predicate" ng-show="$index<5 || form.showMoreQuestions" >
<!--section for question and option to answer-->
    <span class="pull-left" style="margin-bottom:5px">
        <ul style="color:#107A77; margin-left: -10px; list-style-type:none">
            <li >
                <!--below is only to toggle form view-->
                <h7><strong><a style="color:#107A77;" ng-click="o.Answer = true" ng-show="!o.Answer">Comment</a></strong></h7>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h7 ng-init="replyCounter=o.replyCounter">Replies&nbsp; ({{replyCounter}}) </h7>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h7>
                <a style="color:#107A77;text-size: 6px" 
                    ng-init="followCounter=o.followCounter" ng-click="followConversation(o.id); o.isFollowing=true;
                    followCounter=followCounter+1" ng-show="!o.isFollowing"> 
                    Follow&nbsp;&nbsp; ({{followCounter}}) 
                </a>
                <span ng-show="o.isFollowing">
                    Following&nbsp;&nbsp; ({{followCounter}}) 
                </span>
                </h7>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </span>
    <span ng-show="o.isFollowing">
        <a style='color:gold' ng-init="followCounter = o.followCounter" ng-click="unfollowConversation(o.followId); o.isFollowing = false; 
        followCounter = followCounter-1 " ng-hide="o.unfollowValue">Unfollow</a>
    </span>
    <!--form div below showing only submit and cancel-->
    <div style="margin-top:5px">
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" ng-init="replyCounter=o.replyCounter" style='background:#107A77' 
            ng-click="submitAnswer(o.id); replyCounter = replyCounter+1;">Submit</button>
            &nbsp;
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"  style='background:red' ng-click="o.Answer = false" ng-show="o.Answer">Cancel</button>
     </div>
<div class = "col-md-offset-1" style="padding:5px"ng-repeat="a in o.replies" ng-show="$index<3 || o.showMoreReplies">
    <span ng-show="a.isAuthor">
        <a ng-init="replyCounter=o.replyCounter"style='color:red' ng-click="doDelete(a.id); a.deleteValue = true;  
        replyCounter = replyCounter-1">Delete</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

I also included the followCounter as an exmaple of a counter that is working. Pretty much the main problem is in the last inner div that does ng-repeat="a in o.replies" and I'm not sure how to solve the problem of incrementing/decremeting the counter in the overall scope.

Comment: It would be much easier if you can provide a plunkr that shows the problem. Also, your should use controllers more rather than ng-init or complex ng-clicks.

Comment: Yes you are right. I think all the ng-init were confusing me because I did not think a scope inside could change a scope outside but it seems to be the case. As long as the display is {{o.replyCounter}} and the ng-click in the response portion is o.replyCounter = o.replyCounter-1